# How do I use snakemake --cluster-cancel?

Tags: cluster-computing, snakemake

I currently have a snakemake pipeline running with multiple jobs on a cluster. I want to cancel my jobs early, and the snakemake documentation says that I can use the `--cluster-cancel` option. However, it doesn't have any example of how to use it. The cluster I am using cancels jobs with `qdel`. So, I tried using `snakemake --cluster-cancel "qdel"`, but when I do this it returns the error

`snakemake: error: unrecognized arguments: --cluster-cancel`

Comment: Which version of Snakemake are you using?

Comment: I am using snakemake version 6.14.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using `snakemake >= v7.0.0`.

Then set `--cluster-cancel qdel` or`--cluster-cancel scancel` depending on whether the job scheduling system is PBS or SLURM.

You can also set this in the `config.yaml` as `cluster-cancel: qdel` etc.

If you use SLURM, you must add the `--parsable` flag to the `sbatch` command passed via `--cluster`.

This is an example `config.yaml` for SLURM:

```yaml
cluster: "sbatch --time={cluster.time} --cpus-per-task={cluster.n} --parsable"
cluster-cancel: scancel
```

Related question: ["scancel: error: Invalid job id Submitted batch job" with --cluster-cancel from snakemake](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74595582/scancel-error-invalid-job-id-submitted-batch-job-with-cluster-cancel-from)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used the `--cluster-cancel` feature, but have the following routine whenever I want to kill a bunch of snakemake jobs on my cluster.

1. Interrupt the snakemake pipeline: `^C`
2. Kill existing jobs on the cluster: `bkill 0` (kills all jobs) or `bkill [jobid]`
3. Unlock the snakemake pipeline for future use: `snakemake --unlock`

Comment: Yeah, I used to do that, but my problem is that I have a couple different pipelines running on different folders and it is tedious to sort out which jobs belong to which instance of snakemake and kill them individually.

Answer (score 0):

`--cluster-cancel` is a feature that was introduced in version 7.0.0. If you’re able to use that or a newer version on the cluster, you ought to be able to use that feature in the way you tried.

Comment: But how exactly do you use it? What's the argument that `--cluster-cancel` takes? Simply the command `scancel` or a template like `scancel {jobid}` or something like that?

Comment: Good catch, I focused too much on the version issue