# "scancel: error: Invalid job id Submitted batch job" with --cluster-cancel from snakemake

Tags: snakemake

I am running snakemake using this command:

`snakemake --profile slurm -j 1 --cores 1 --cluster-cancel "scancel"`

which writes this to standard out:

`Submitted job 224 with external jobid 'Submitted batch job 54174212'.`

but after I cancel the run with `ctrl + c`, I get the following error:

`scancel: error: Invalid job id Submitted batch job 54174212`

What I would guess is that the jobid is `'Submitted batch job 54174212'`
and snakemake tries to run `scancel 'Submitted batch job 54174212'` instead of the expected `scancel 54174212`. If this is the case, how do I change the jobid to something that works with scancel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your suspicion is probably correct, `snakemake` probably tries to cancel the wrong job (id `Submitted batch job 54174212`).

Check your `slurm` profile for `snakemake` which you invoke (standard location `~/.config/snakemake/slurm/config.yaml`):
Does it contain the [`--parsable` flag for `sbatch`](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sbatch.html#OPT_parsable)?

Missing to include that flag is a mistake I made before. Adding the flag solved it for me.